# deciding Minutes Vs Seconds in python

Tags: python, time

I'm working on a dataset that has time in a data frame as:
'23:04:44',
'39:03:22'

```
for h in df.time:
   hours.append(h[3:5])
for s in df.time:
   seconds.append(s[0:2])
for m in df.time:
   minutes.append(m[6:8])
print(min(hours),max(hours))
print(min(seconds),max(seconds))
print(min(minutes),max(minutes))
```

Gives the result:

('00', '22'),
('00', '59'),
('00', '58')

Through the above result, it can be concluded h[3:5] are hours and the other two values can be either seconds or minutes, however, how can we decide which value can be assumed as a minute or second?

Comment: Where are you confused with this?  You control the reporting order.  You defined the output as hours, seconds, and minutes, in that order.

Comment: Times are usually written as `hh:mm:ss` or as `hh:mm`. But you seem to be extracting it as `ss:hh:mm`, which is very weird.

Comment: There's no way you can automatically tell which fields are which. The best you can do is if there's and field that contains values higher than 23, it's not hours. But there's no way to figure out which is minutes versus seconds, because they both can hold any values from 0 to 59.